# Minimum number of studies to meta-analyze in random-effects GLM models

Tags: random-effects-model, meta-analysis

I have a question regarding the use of random-effects GLM meta-analytic models and the minimum number of studies needed and its relation to the estimation of $ \tau^2 $. (I understand that only two studies are needed for a fixed effect estimate.)

My hunch is that one needs at least $k=4$ studies, since 1 degree of freedom will be used for the average effect estimate and the remaining 3 will then go towards estimation of $\tau$. However, I have see published reports that will report random-effects estimates with $k=2$ studies, and indeed any popular meta-analytic packages will fit such models because it is mathematically possible. With so few studies, will $\hat{\tau}^2$ be meaningful? or (badly) biased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that it is likely to be imprecisely estimated. The preferred way of showing this is to present it with a confidence interval but this is not often done. An article by Ioannidis and colleagues in the British Medical Journal [here](http://www.bmj.com/content/335/7626/914) entitled "Uncertainty in heterogeneity estimates in meta-analyses" argues for the routine presentation of confidence intervals. Any meta-analysis based on a few studies would need to be treated with caution anyway but perhaps some extra caution is needed if a random effects model is proposed.

Comment: I agree with you on the imprecision point. Certainly a model with few studies and heterogeneity could yield very wide confidence intervals.